# Displaying mp4 file with html

Tags: html, gif, mp4

Hello guys im struggling with displaying gif image in mp4 format:

```
<video width="320" height="240" >
  <source src="http://media4.giphy.com//media//64zSh1uTE7xxm//100w.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

that's my code, but only first frame is beeing loaded, then everything freezes.
//
edit 
I have remade it into this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <video width="320" height="240" >
  <source src="http://media4.giphy.com//media//64zSh1uTE7xxm//100w.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay/>
</video> 
</body>
</html>
```

but still its static image.

edit2// I'have added

```
controls="controls"
```

since In XHTML, attribute minimization is forbidden, and the autoplay attribute must be defined as video autoplay="autoplay".

Comment: I tried all the responses with no luck so far. At the end I went with converting the mp4 file to gif format using one of the many websites available out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to play the video, too, because by default it will pause at 0:00. There are 3 possible solutions to this problem.

1. Use the `controls` attribute (`<video ... controls>`) to show the
   controls and play it manually
2. Use the `autoplay` attribute (`<video ... autoplay>`) to
   autmatically play the video once it has loaded
3. Get the element via JavaScript and play it there (same behaviour as
   autoplay in this solution):

   ```
   var video = document.getElementById ("videoElement");
   video.addEventListener ("loadedmetadata", function () { video.play (); });
   ```

For further information on HTML5-Video attributes, check out MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too proficient in HTML myself, but I've experienced this problem too. The reason why the video is frozen on the first frame is because, by default, the video is *paused* at 0:00, which means it will simply not play without user intervention or code to play itself. There are two solutions to this:

1. Either include **controls** to this video, which can be done by changing the `<video width="320" height="240">` to `<video width="320" height="240" controls>` or
2. Include **autoplay** by adding the `autoplay` attribute, which can be done by again changing `<video width="320" height="240">` to `<video width="320" height="240" autoplay>`.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Add the **autoplay** property to the video tag, e.g.:

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the full construction.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls> </video>
```

instead of **controls** you can use other attributes.

- autoplay - Specifies that the video will start playing as soon as it is ready
- controls - Specifies that video controls should be displayed (such as a play/pause button etc).
- height- Sets the height of the video player
- loop -   Specifies that the video will start over again, every time it is finished
- muted -      Specifies that the audio output of the video should be muted
- poster -     Specifies an image to be shown while the video is downloading, or until the user hits the play button
- preload - Specifies if and how the author thinks the video should be loaded when the page loads
- src -    Specifies the URL of the video file
- width -      Sets the width of the video player

For more informations go to: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_video.asp)

Comment: This is a nice answer, but a nitpick here: they're not called parameters, but rather attributes. Also, let's try not to copy paste from external websites. (But does it solve the question?)

Comment: @Jerrybibo
Thanks. OK i will remember that:)
Yea it should. I have tried it myself.